# Length of the entire tan() function cut off by two lines in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-2 * np.pi, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
y = np.tan(x)
y2 = 4 + x*0
y3 = -4 + x*0
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) 

diffs = np.sqrt(np.diff(x)**2+np.diff(y)**2)
length = diffs.sum()

numbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
p2 = []
for i in range(len(numbers)):
            cumlenth = np.cumsum(diffs)
            s = np.abs(np.diff(np.sign(cumlenth-numbers[i]))).astype(bool)
            c = np.argwhere(s)[0][0]
            p = x[c], y[c]
            p2.append(p)
            ax.cla()
            ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for j in range(len(p2)):   
            ax.scatter(p2[j][0],p2[j][1], color="crimson", s=5)

plt.plot(np.tan(x))
plt.plot(y2)
plt.plot(y3)
plt.ylim(-10, 10)
```

I'm trying to find the length of the `tan()` function cut off by two lines `y2`, `y3` in a certain compartment. This means that only the part marked in red below should be taken to the total length of the chart:

[image]

Next, I try to mark the position of a points from list `numbers = []` on this the graph, which are lying in the distance equal to the value of these points, starting from the beginning of the graph in point `(x,y)=(0,0)`, and I want get their coordinates. Which for my sample list `numbers = []` would give something like this:

[image]

What am I missing? Can this be achieved? 
I will be grateful for any tips.

Comment: It looks that you add segment where tan becomes singular. Try to filter out diffs above some fixed threshold like 5 in your case

Comment: Are you familiar with the term [Arc Length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length) ? You'll have to do numeric integration. Solve for the x bounds first. As a repeating function, you'll want to just calculate it for one instance, then multiply, then calculate it for the 2 ends.

Comment: @o11c I know the theory, but a lot of time will go down before I can introduce this idea to a problem :)

Comment: You seem to have picked arbitrary steps for x which will probably not match the cut-off range y2 and y3 and then you’ll either lose accuracy or have to iterate to get better accuracy. Why not work out in advance the values of x which correspond to tan(x)==y2 and tan(x)==y3 - i.e. the range from inverse tan(y2) to inverse tan(y3)?

Comment: @barny interesting idea, I'll try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.plot` takes two arguments, an `x` array and a `y` array; without providing both, `pyplot` assumes that you wanted to plot them against the index of the value in the array. So, your first hurdle is to change the lines at the bottom to:

```
plt.plot(x, np.tan(x))
plt.plot(x, y2)
plt.plot(x, y3)
```

Now we have the issue of the fact that your calculation is taking the whole graph into account, not just the parts between -4 and 4. You could solve this by filtering the x array by your thresholds:

```
x_all   = np.linspace(-2 * np.pi, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
x_above = x_all[ -4 < np.tan(x_all) ]
x       = x_above[ np.tan(x_above) < 4 ]
```

Finally, we have the issue that the diff calculation seems to be taking the jump from +4 to -4 into account. We can mitigate this by filtering out anywhere the diff in `y` is negative:

```
y_up   = np.diff(y) > 0
y_diff = np.where( y_up, np.diff(y), 0 )
x_diff = np.where( y_up, np.diff(x), 0 )
diffs = np.sqrt( x_diff**2 + y_diff**2 )
```

My final code looks like this, and seems to be working as you expect it to:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x_all   = np.linspace(-2 * np.pi, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
x_above = x_all[ -4 < np.tan(x_all) ]
x       = x_above[ np.tan(x_above) < 4 ]
y       = np.tan(x)
y2      = 4 + x*0
y3      = -4 + x*0

y_up   = np.diff(y) > 0
y_diff = np.where( y_up, np.diff(y), 0 )
x_diff = np.where( y_up, np.diff(x), 0 )
diffs  = np.sqrt( x_diff**2 + y_diff**2 )
length = diffs.sum()

numbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
p2 = []
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    cumlenth = np.cumsum(diffs)
    s = np.abs(np.diff(np.sign(cumlenth-numbers[i]))).astype(bool)
    c = np.argwhere(s)[0][0]
    p = x[c], y[c]
    p2.append(p)

for j in range(len(p2)):
    plt.scatter( p2[j][0], p2[j][1], color="crimson", s=5)

plt.plot(x, np.tan(x))
plt.plot(x, y2)
plt.plot(x, y3)
plt.ylim(-10, 10)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! I also realised that the graph didn't _look_ as if it were evenly spacing the points along the line, until I realised the aspect ratio was out - try adding:
`ax = plt.gca()`
`ax.set_aspect("equal")`
right before the `plt.show()` and that makes the plot a little more obvious.